# What are the Spiritual Gifts?

Tags: bible, spiritual-gifts

People often talk about spiritual gifts, like tongues and prophecy. What spiritual gifts are mentioned in the Bible? Please provide references.

Comment: I realise this is a list question, but it is a strictly limited list and very important, so I hope this one survives.

Comment: Here's an almost succinct Catholic Encyclopedia article [on Charismata](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/03588e.htm).  Might aid the answer, but not all the gifts listed have biblical references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritual_gift) has a decent article on this subject. There are a few places in the Bible where lists of spiritual gifts occur, which are, according to Wikipedia, as follows:

Romans 12:6-8:

- Prophecy
- Serving
- Teaching
- Exhortation
- Giving
- Leadership
- Mercy

1 Corinthians 12:8-10:

- Word of wisdom
- Word of knowledge
- Faith
- Gifts of healings
- Miracles
- Prophecy
- Distinguishing between spirits
- Tongues
- Interpretation of tongues

1 Corinthians 12:28:

- Apostle
- Prophet
- Teacher
- Miracles
- Kinds of healings
- Helps
- Administration
- Tongues

Ephesians 4:11:

- Apostle
- Prophet
- Evangelist
- Pastor
- Teacher

<sup>Note that Wikipedia lists those last two as one entry: Pastor-teacher - but they are more commonly listed as separate items.</sup>

1 Peter 4:11:

- Whoever speaks
- Whoever renders service

It could be argued that not all of these are spiritual gifts - some might be better referred to as roles or activities; also different versions of the Bible will use slightly different wording for some of these so it's important to look into the context and meaning of the relevant passages.

In addition, there are other places in the Bible where spiritual gifts are mentioned, but not necessarily as part of a list. A good example is this:

> Then the LORD said to Moses, “See, I have chosen Bezalel son of
>   Uri, the son of Hur, of the tribe of Judah, and I have filled him
>   with the Spirit of God, with wisdom, with understanding, with
>   knowledge and with all kinds of skills— to make artistic designs for
>   work in gold, silver and bronze, to cut and set stones, to work in
>   wood, and to engage in all kinds of crafts.

--[Exodus 31:1-5 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2031:1-5&version=NIV)

And then there are other gifts, in such as abilities, talents and more (a good example being someone who is musically gifted); it's next to impossible to really give a definitive list because:

> Every good and perfect gift is from above, coming down from the Father of the heavenly lights, who does not change like shifting shadows.

-- [James 1:17 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%201:17&version=NIV)

Comment: I like your formatting better :)

Comment: I think to make this complete, you need to add [Bezalel](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2031:1-5&version=NIV1984) who had a [craft gift](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2035:30-33&version=NIV1984). And there may be an example of God giving someone a musical gift as well.

Comment: @Wikis Thanks, Bezalel is a great example. Duly added, along with James 1:17 - quite an important verse to consider on this subject.

Comment: Thanks. One note: the "pastor-teacher" in Ephesians is typically listed as two items, "pastor, teacher". I suggest you edit your answer to say, "pastor-teacher, or pastor and teacher" (or similar).

Comment: Also, singleness and marriage in 1 Corinthians 7:7 are spiritual gifts (charismata).

Answer (score 4):

There are (non-mutually exclusive) two lists of spiritual gifts in the early church, one found in Ephesians 4, the other in 1 Corinthians 12:

Here they are:

> To one there is given through the Spirit the message of wisdom,
>
> to another the message of knowledge by means of the same Spirit,
>
> to another faith by the same Spirit,
>
> to another gifts of healing by that one Spirit,
>
> to another miraculous powers,
>
> to another prophecy,
>
> to another distinguishing between spirits,
>
> to another speaking in different kinds of tongues,
>
> and to still another the interpretation of tongues.
>
> All these are the work of one and the same Spirit, and he gives them to each one, just as he determines.

And from Ephesians 4:

> It was he who gave some to be apostles,
>
> some to be prophets,
>
> some to be evangelists,
>
> and some to be pastors and teachers, to prepare God's people for works of service, so that the body of Christ may be built up

The spiritual gifts in Romans 12 are listed not as an exhortation to unity but rather to action:

> We have different gifts, according to the grace given to each of us. If your gift is prophesying, then prophesy in accordance with your faith; if it is serving, then serve; if it is teaching, then teach; if it is to encourage, then give encouragement; if it is giving, then give generously; if it is to lead, do it diligently; if it is to show mercy, do it cheerfully